# How can I add to shortcodes?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have plugin A that needs to verify two pieces of shortcodes before an action takes place within another plugin.

```
    <?php
function mepr_add_some_tabs($user) {
  ?>
    <span class="mepr-nav-item prem-support <?php MeprAccountHelper::active_nav('member-profile'); ?>">
      <!-- KEEPS THE USER ON THE ACCOUNT PAGE -->
      <a href="/account/?action=member-profile">Profile</a>
    </span>
  <?php
}
add_action('mepr_account_nav', 'mepr_add_some_tabs');

function mepr_add_tabs_content($action) {
  //Listens for the "member-profile" action on the account page, before rendering the FF view shortcode.
  if($action == 'member-profile') {
    echo do_shortcode('[frm-condition source=frm-stats id=80 type=count user_id=current greater_than=0] [display-frm-data id=5728] [/frm-condition]');
  }
}
add_action('mepr_account_nav_content', 'mepr_add_tabs_content');
```

The problem is I'm not a developer and I don't know how to add the second shortcode in the echo do_shortcode function.

The current shortcode basically says: if the user has an entry on the field ID: 80, then show them the content of the entry.
What I need to add is another, second shortcode which will say almost the same thing, but about another field ID.

How can I add it while following this requirement?

Comment: Use the same `do_shortcode()` line, but change 80 to the other ID?

Comment: SO is about helping developers, but the code can be added using a text editor.

Comment: @kmoser But do I add it inside the brackets, or do I just add a new echo do_shortcode()?

Comment: @camfil26 How about trying it both ways and letting us know if either of them worked?